# How to handle Google Tango errors caused by user

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

When a user hold a Tango device the wrong way/blocks the device cameras, the OS displays following message:
"Nothing detected:
Keep the device at least an arm's length from object..."

Is it possible in the Unity Google Tango SDK to detect when this happens?
It's causing my app to become inaccurate and previously placed 3d objects appear at the wrong location.
It would be useful if this error could be handled in code, so the app can show a message to request the user to recalibrate to the app.